# Facebook Like icon not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, facebook

When adding the [facebook like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) into my page, it aligns with text in the body of the page, but not the navbar, where it will appear higher than the rest of the text. I was able to fix this by lowering its relative position, but this causes it to display lower on the mobile version of the page.

Is there a simple solution that I'm missing that will allow me to display the element in line with text both on desktop and mobile? [My site can be found here](http://warsofliberty.com/music), if that helps. Thank you!

Edit: Code example here for the fixed position button:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><span style="position:relative; top:15px" class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/WarsofLiberty/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" data-colorscheme="light"></span>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home <span class="border"></span></span></a></li></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You need to add code.... what have you tried? Add a fiddle...You cant expect answer without showing what you have done...unless you want to pay for someone to do it...

Comment: Just added code! You can also see an example in the header of the site..

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
.fb-like {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: parent height;

    }
```

Comment: Adding this to the current style doesn't seem to do anything, and replacing the current style with it moves it back up to the top of the page. vertical-aligns don't seem to be working with this element for whatever reason.